# Classica ASP: Log file

Tags: asp-classic

Currently I am working on a very huge ASP application. I want to find a log component for classical asp, which allow me use this component to log some information of ASP application.

I know in .NET application, we can log4net. Is any similar components for classical ASP application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately classic asp is outdated and it's not like php where you can just go out and find a component for everything. You're going to have to do some manual work as far as I'm concerned there's really not much out there that will do what you expect it to do.  But I do have good news, there are things out there which will make your work a bit easier:

---

### IIS Logging:

The web server [IIS comes with logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524845%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you just have to [enable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754631%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) it.

*By default, logging is enabled in IIS 7.*

But this is if you would just like to log the incoming/outgoing requests on a web server level and not the nitty gritty stuff like user/session data.

---

### Custom Errors:

You can [set-up custom errors](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/jamie-furr/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/) to log information to a file or database when a certain status code is returned to the user, but you would have to write this part yourself based on your needs.

A good example of using custom errors would be is if you want to log application errors, which in this case I probably would if its a large app, you can save them into a gemeric log database table, assuming you have a database available.

To catch the application errors, which you will want to do with a large asp app, you can refer to Michael Pryors answer here [Classic ASP - Catching 500 Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987577/classic-asp-catching-500-errors) then you can save it to text file or database, I would do a database for queryability.